# What is the accepted naming convention for web form backing objects in Java/Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, naming-conventions

I have a Java web application built using Spring MVC.   I have a set of JSPs which are the pages, and a set of "model" objects which are sent to the JSPs to populate/receive the form data.   Here is a simplified view from the JSP down to the database layer:

```
showCustomer.jsp  // JSP page using the "CustomerViewDao"
org.mycompany.views.CustomerViewDao  // view backing (model) object
org.mycompany.controller.CustomerController // controller layer
org.mycompany.service.CustomerService // service layer
org.mycompany.model.Customer // Hibernate entity
```

Is there an accepted naming convention for these model objects?   I chose "xxxDao" for "Data Access Object" and was told this was not a "good" choice.   Is there a better choice and what would it be?

Comment: It's offen called "command", so in your example you could use " CustomerCommand".

Comment: How are you passing your model to the page?  Are you using Spring Web Forms?  JSTL?  JSF?  Something else?

Comment: It is the Model in MVC (object which is represented by view), so name it `CustomerModel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there is no "accepted naming convention".   However, some people have good ideas about these things ... e.g. trawl through the answers to this: [What naming convention do you use for the service layer in a Spring MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995473/what-naming-convention-do-you-use-for-the-service-layer-in-a-spring-mvc-applicat)

For what it is worth, I probably would have chosen `xxxDao` too ... assuming that the object really is a DAO.  But obviously, your reviewer had different ideas.  You should ask *him* (or her) for suggestions ... not us!  (What is to say that he won't arbitrarily reject your next N choices as being "not good"?)

---

On the other hand, he might have rejected your choice of "xxxDAO" because the object / class is not a DAO (Data Access Object) in the normal sense of that term.  Your description ... "view-backed (model) object" ... does not really match the normal usage of DAO.

Answer (score 0):

I had called it: ShowCustomerBean